# How camera size affects render quality?

Tags: rendering, camera

I would like to know, how the size of camera contributes to the render quality? We set the resolution in output properties. But I still, I have a doubt of whether or not the camera size contributes.

Comment: Hello, could you specifiy exactly what you mean by the "size" of the camera ?

Comment: if you ask does it change something to scale the camera in the 3D view, I don't think so, it just makes it more visible if it's tiny

Answer (score 3):

The ***Camera Size*** in the 3D viewport will make no difference in the qualities of the rendered image. Changing the size is meant to help you find and visualize the camera while you set the scene.

The ***Sensor Size*** will make a difference in the *characteristics* of the image, if it used in combination with the ***Lens Size*** and ***f-Stop*** to control depth of field (meaning how sharp, or blurry, the objects will be if they are closer to the focus distance or further away from it).

The ***Render Size*** in pixels, or [*resolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_resolution) will determine how large the image will be, and how it is represented in a monitor (or whatever other media is used to display it). The more pixels the image has will have an impact on the amount of detail and how large the image can be displayed, or printed, before it is no longer sharp.

Comment: Thank you very much @susu